A monster-taming cartoon featuring an episode set in a canyon town
I'm trying to identify a cartoon show I watched around 2014. It was in English. The show featured cool monsters, and I think they could be tamed with a phone or some other type of technology, kind of like Pokémon or Dinosaur King. It followed a group of three or so people.
I remember an episode where they were flying over a canyon with a little town in it that one of them was from. The one that was from there had their phone shock and vibrate because their old monster friend from when they were a kid was nearby or something along those lines.
Sorry for being super vague, but this is all that I can remember from it.

Is there any chance this could be Digimon?
It's a very Pokémon-like show where a group of seven children are transported to a Digital World inhabited by Pokémon-like creatures called Digimons, and each child befriends and is partnered with a Digimon that they use cellphone-like "Digivices" to interact with.
I don't remember the specific scene you describe but it absolutely sounds like something that could have happened in the show, in particular in a later season - I think there is a generation skip at some point where the original 7 have grown up and their younger siblings have the adventures, and there are reunion scenes between the OG characters and their Digimon.
It's an anime but absolutely ran in English on Anglo TV, I saw in in the US around 2000.
Digimon poster:

Poster for the sequel, generation-skipped series:

Drawing of some OG characters and a Digivice (from the Digimon Wiki):

